# Import recovered Innodb database

Tags: database, innodb, recover

I had recovered deleted .frm and .ibd files with Recuva. It looks okay, but...

I tried to create a database and import a older backup, and just replace new files with recovered = many errors.

When I searched how to do that and found this:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name DISCARD TABLESPACE;
```

shutdown mysql and copy recovered files

start mysql

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

And then I get this error:

```
#1034 - Incorrect key file for table 'tbl_name'; try to repair it
```

Repair not working:

```
The storage engine for the table doesn't support r..
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: File recovery tools usually don't work well* with databases. Besides, ibd file itself is not enough InnoDB dictionary (which is in ibdata1) should be aware of the table you're importing.
* - update

Comment: you can follow [this](http://www.chriscalender.com/recovering-an-innodb-table-from-only-an-ibd-file/) to recover from .ibd and .frm files